# I have a error with hdfs hadoop file and Idk what is the problem

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

when a put:

`hfs dfs -put /Users/mariajesuscanoles/Desktop/test/word.txt /Users/mariajesuscanoles`

I have this error, and idk how fix it:

```
2022-07-03 14:39:16,022 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: `/Users/mariajesuscanoles': No such file or directory: `hdfs://localhost:8020/Users/mariajesuscanoles'
```

And I'm using mac

Answer (score 0):

HDFS doesn't have a default `/Users` folder like a Mac.

It will only have the directories that you've created with `hdfs mkdir`

Hadoop prefers you use `/user/` (singular, lowercase), anyway

Answer (score 0):

> /Users/mariajesuscanoles': No such file or directory:

It is just telling **/Users** directory doesn't exits.

I suppose your assumption is that there is a user home directory named  '**/User/mariajesuscanoles**' already there in HDFS which isn't true.

Do a hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /User/mariajesuscanoles and it should create this directory and then you can try your put command.

BTW. the default prefix for User home directory in HDFS is **/user** not **/User**, If you want to change it you can do so by changing the value of config: `dfs.user.home.dir.prefix`